# gif restart / smooth loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

ok, so i’m building a front end for a watson interface and i bought like 6 gif animations that are supposed to embody the AI. much like how siri has her waveform when she speaks.

So i’m using a div with the background-image style property being set to url( “pathto”). this works great, however it will have a gap between the load and unload of the gif if i do this in javascript.

on the other hand, i tried creating css classes that each contain the properties “background-image: url( “pathto” )” for their individual animations and this works without a gap, however the animation is constantly playing in the background so when you switch to one and it’s already been loaded, it will pick up where it is and make it look very out of sync.

here's the class version:

```
.ai-thinking-spinner {
    background-image: url( "assets/ai-thinking-spinner.gif" );
}

.ai-idle {
    background-image: url( "assets/ai-idle.png" );
}

.ai-initialization {
    background-image: url( "assets/ai-initialization.gif" );
}

.ai-initialization-idle {
    background-image: url( "assets/ai-initialization-idle.png" );
}

.ai-speaking {
    background-image: url( "assets/ai-speaking.gif" );
}
```

js:

```
app.changeAISource = function( clazz ) {
    // Not included here, but removes all of the classes above here
    $( "#ai-body" ).addClass( clazz );
}
```

the other version of switching them is done like so:

```
app.changeAISource = function( src ) {
    $( "#ai-body" ).css( "background-image", "url( " + src + " )" );
}
```

I also tried re-querying the image like so:

```
app.changeAISource = function( clazz ) {
    $( "#ai-body" ).css( "background-image", "url( " + clazz + "" + new Date().now() +  " )" );
}
```

but it again causes a gap for loading.

any suggestions?

Comment: Provide some codes please.

Comment: @AbhishekSinha just added some